# Total Views Count for a User

Tags: python, django

Here's the **model**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ......
    ......
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How can I print the total number of `views` for a `specific user` for all the answers he/she have ever written?

Please help me, thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_views = Answer.objects.get(user=user).aggregate(Sum('views'))
```

If you want to get a sum for a list of users, such as users with ids of [1, 5, 7, 12], you can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

ids = [1, 5, 7, 12]

views_list = Answer.objects.filter(user__pk__in=ids).annotate(num_views = Sum('views'))
```

Then you would access each one by:

```
print(views_list[0].num_views)
```

Comment: Sir, it's raising an error that get returned more than 1 Answer. Replacing 'get' with 'filter' is giving results something like {'views__sum': 11}. How can I get normal results?

Comment: Efficient solution Timm. Dodval you should consider using this since its faster and does not use so much memory. What do you mean by "Normal results", you need just the number?

Comment: Dodval, I assumed you were looking to get the number for an individual user.  Are you trying to do it for all users?

Comment: I edited it a bit.  Maybe that will help.  Use annotate for each individual in a queryset, and use aggregate for the entire set.

Comment: I just thought to ask.  Are you wanting to get all views for all users?  If that's the case, I believe you can aggregate the second one by adding `.aggregate(Sum(num_views))` to the end.

Comment: Or you could just `Answer.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('views'))`

Comment: @TimmSimpkins Sir, your solution is working perfectly fine. But I couldn't print out the results like '11' instead of 'views__sum: 11'.                           
 Just being a newbie :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @TimmSimpkins Sir, total_views = Answer.objects.get(user=user).aggregate(Sum('views')) this solution is working Perfectly fine as I wanted it to be. But in template {{ total_views }} is giving results something like 'views__sum: 11', how can I get '11' instead of 'views__sum: 11' ?

Comment: Use `{{ total_views.views__sum }}`, or you can try changing the query to `Answer.objects.get(user=user).aggregate(Sum('views')).values()[0]`

Comment: @TimmSimpkins Wow, Everything worked out Perfectly. Thank You very much Sir :) :)